# how to convert native machine code to llvm bytecode

Tags: llvm

Is there a machanism to convert native machine code to llvm bytecode?
If not, please give some idea how to implement it.

Thanks!

Comment: I highly doubt that *any* given machine code could be converted to LLVM bytecode.  Perhaps some specific sequences could be converted, but writing a converter that would work on any input is likely impossible.  (Or would require emulation of the target CPU inside the VM, which would of course defeat the purpose...)

Comment: I have similar question : [Translation of machinecode into LLVM IR (disassembly / reassembly of X86_64. X86. ARM into LLVM bitcode)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981810/translation-of-machinecode-into-llvm-ir-disassembly-reassembly-of-x86-64-x86) - you might be interested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Libcpu](https://github.com/libcpu/libcpu) was designed to convert machine code of various architectures to LLVM IR to facilitate writing emulators.