# Translation of machinecode into LLVM IR (disassembly / reassembly of X86_64. X86. ARM into LLVM bitcode)

Tags: translation, llvm, assembly, disassembly, opcode

I would like to translate X86_64, x86, ARM executables into LLVM IR (disassembly).

What solution do you suggest ?

Comment: I've checked llvm-objdump, but as far as I understand, it produces x86_64/x86 assembler - what I want is LLVM assembler.

Comment: There are plenty of disassemblers for x86_86, x86, arm. Maybe some assemlber compiler with target "LLVM IR" ?

Comment: That's not disassembly, that's translation!

Comment: At least for the X86 part of your question, there is http://blog.llvm.org/2010/01/x86-disassembler.html

Answer (score 16):

mcsema is a production-quality binary lifter. It takes x86 and x86-64 and statically "lifts" it to LLVM IR. It's actively maintained, BSD licensed, and has extensive tests and documentation.

https://github.com/trailofbits/mcsema

Comment: but it requires a PRO license of IDA

Answer (score 11):

Consider using [**RevGen**](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/166081/files/revgen.pdf) tool developed within the [**S2E project**](http://dslab.epfl.ch/proj/s2e). It allows converting x86 binaries to LLVM IR. The source code could be checked out from Revgen branch of GIT repository available by url *https://dslabgit.epfl.ch/git/s2e/s2e.git*.

Comment: I see you've [mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9059978/544721) another [paper](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/149975/files/x86-llvm-translator-chipounov_2.pdf) related with x86 -> LLVM translation. Thanks for great references.

Comment: I have problems with links provided. `git clone https://dslabgit.epfl.ch/git/s2e/s2e.git` can not clone :/.

Comment: I haven't got any problems on Ubuntu 10.10. Make sure you have git installed and correct firewall/proxy settings. Also you may find some related documentation on project's web site _https://s2e.epfl.ch/embedded/s2e/index.html_

Comment: Ok, now it works. Probably it was temporary network problem or short server downtime. I'd love to take a look at RevGen asap :).

Comment: Grzegorz Wierzowiecki, is here an ready-to-use converted from x86 binary into llvm ir? What part of s2e.git is the revgen itself?

Comment: Hi osgx, you can find it at **<s2e_root>/tools/tools/static-translator**.

Answer (score 10):

As regards to **RevGen** tool mentioned by @bsa2000, this latest paper ["A compiler level intermediate representation based binary analysis and rewriting system"](http://eurosys2013.tudos.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/paper/Anand.pdf) has pointed out some limitations in S2E and Revinc.

I pull them out here.

1. shortcoming of dynamic translation:

   > S2E [16] and Revnic [14] present a method for dynamically translating
   >   x86 to LLVM using QEMU. Unlike our approach, these methods convert
   >   blocks of code to LLVM on the fly which limits the application of LLVM
   >   analyses to only one block at a time.
2. IR incomplete:

   > Revnic [14] and RevGen [15] recover an IR by merging the translated
   >   blocks, but the recovered IR is incomplete and is only valid for
   >   current execution; consequently, various whole program analyses will
   >   provide incomplete information.
3. no abstract stack or promoting information

   > Further, the translated code retains all the assumptions of the
   >   original bi- nary about the stack layout. They do not provide any
   >   methods for obtaining an abstract stack or promoting memory locations
   >   to symbols, which are essential for the application of several
   >   source-level analyses.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there will be universal solution (think about indirect branches, etc.), LLVM IR is much "higher level" than any assembler. Though it's possible to translate on per-BB basis. You might want to check llvm-qemu and libcpu projects among others.

Comment: LLVM is able to capture high level information, IMHO it is not required. I believe there can exist solution - maybe not one universal approach, but still. Thanks for great references : llvm-qemu and libcpu looks interesting. :)

Comment: Btw. If there [is possible LLVM to Javascript trsnalation and it's actually implemented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295922/what-platform-can-i-compile-binaries-for-using-llvm-low-level-virtual-machine/7325817#7325817), another assembly is possible as well ;). Question, you and when will do it :).

Answer (score 1):

Just post some references on translating ARM binary to LLVM IR:

disarm - arm binary to llvm ir disassembler

https://code.google.com/p/disarm/

However, I have not tried it, thus not sure about its quality and stability. Anyone else may post additional information about this project?

Comment: It seems that the author have withdrew it... Fortunately, I have a local svn to backup its code.

Answer (score 1):

There is new project, being in some early phases, The `libbeauty`:
https://github.com/jcdutton/libbeauty

Article about project: *Libbeauty: Another Reverse-Engineering Tool*, 24 December 2013, Michael Larabel - http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTU1MTU

It only supports subset of `x86_64` as input now. One of the project goals - is to be able to compile the generated LLVM IR back to assembly to get the binary with same functionality.

Comment: Project looks nice! Thanks!

Comment: Project is dead and removed from GitHub.