# Is there x86 assembly front end for llvm?

Tags: assembly, llvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Translation of machinecode into LLVM IR (disassembly / reassembly of X86_64. X86. ARM into LLVM bitcode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981810/translation-of-machinecode-into-llvm-ir-disassembly-reassembly-of-x86-64-x86)

In that way, I can compile the x86 assembly code to llvm bitcode using this front end.
Thanks

Comment: This question was already asked & answered. There is no direct solution due to many stuff (e.g. indirect branches). You might find the project like llvm-qemu and libcpu useful for you. In any case, this question is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981810/translation-of-machinecode-into-llvm-ir-disassembly-reassembly-of-x86-64-x86

Comment: @Anton Korobeynikov: The other question is about dissembling a binary into LLVM IR, which is different than this question. An overly zealous person 'could' make an argument that is is a 'possible duplicate'.  I would hope nobody would call it an "exact duplicate".  Ironically this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014237/source-to-source-compilation-with-llvm/9059978#9059978, where you posted   almost an identical response, is closer to this one.