# Compiling libtool library into LLVM bitcode

Tags: llvm

I am converting an entire project, which include libraries, into LLVM bytecode.

What is the proper way to compile library objects (.lo) and libtool libraries (.la) into LLVM bytecode (.bc)?

EDIT: What I mean is emit LLVM from source code that was meant to compile into .la and .lo.

Comment: You might be interested in [this related question on how to get LLVM bitcode from machine code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981810/translation-of-machinecode-into-llvm-ir-disassembly-reassembly-of-x86-64-x86).

Comment: The proper way is (as of 3.4) to use `-flto` Clang option. Make sure you pass a path to the LLVM gold plugin to your `ar` and `ranlib`, of course.