# LLVM: How to convert an executable to bitcode/ll format?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I have an executable file, which I want to convert back to bc/ ll format. Is there a way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Translation of machinecode into LLVM IR (disassembly / reassembly of X86\_64. X86. ARM into LLVM bitcode)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981810/translation-of-machinecode-into-llvm-ir-disassembly-reassembly-of-x86-64-x86)

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot convert an executable back to its source code.

Comment: IIRC, you can at least map back to source lines if you build with specific debug-support options